# Is OTG a hardware feature in smartphones?

Tags: usb, android, smartphone

Smartphones have OTG micro-USB that allows you to stick in USB drives straight to the phone with a connector. Some phones such as many Windows phones do not have this.

Does OTG require any extra hardware interfacing with the USB port? Or is it just some software with facilitates the data transfer on the phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is typically hardware support (i.e. IC chips)

See [Maxim -  USB On-the-Go Basics](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1822)

> In addition to requiring a dual-role peripheral/host USB controller, OTG requires additional circuitry to support two new protocols, called HNP and SRP.

'''

> Three additions make the transceiver OTG compatible:
>
> - Switchable pull-up and pull-down resistors on D+/D- to allow peripheral or host functionality.
> - Circuitry to monitor and supply 5V power on VBUS as an A-Device, and to monitor and pulse VBUS as >    a B-Device initiating SRP.
> - An ID input pin, which is made available as an output to the ASIC.